# How to set a td floating left in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, css-float, block, html-table, datatables

First of all I am a newbie and english is not my native language, sorry if my question is not so clear.

I am using jquery datatables with responsive plugin to show an image into a cell and other data (about the image) into other cells in the same row. In small screens I only show two cells/tds per row (image and title), but in smaller screens (phone screens) I need to put one cell under another. Tried display block for tds, but only worked in Firefox.

Searching here I found other solution: set tds floating left. It works on Firefox and latest IE (which I don't mind really) but still doesn't work on Chrome. Watching computed style in Chrome I found that user agent is overwriting my css. How can I fix this? 
Lost a lot of time with this issue. I know that tables are tables but I really need it for a clean responsive design.

This is my code simplified for the example:

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>data<td>
      <td>data<td>
      <td>data<td>
      <td>data<td>
    <tr>
  <table>
<div>
```

```css
@media (max-width: 540px) {
    td{
       float: left;
       width: 90%;
    }
}
```

This works on Firefox and latest IE. How to make it work on Chrome? I don't mind if I have to do it with javascript, jquery or css but I really want to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Answer deleted as promised. Are you sure you are not having another issue, I think it may be a caching issue? Try pemtying the cahcne in chrome. Now I have had the upportunity to look at the website in windows chrome and FF as well, it looks OK, no difference at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem solved! As said in question, I'm a newbie and that takes its toll.

I Added a script for google analytics with an include in php, just BEFORE of the html. Obviously, I knew that scripts have to stay inside of the html, but I really didn't notice that was including it before the html!

I don't know why it prevent the floating of the datatables tds only in chrome and safari. Seems like some browsers are not affected if you write such barbarity, but others do.
Hope it will help other rookies breaking the head for similar nonsense.